# pause ansible playbook for user confirmation, whether to run rest tasks

Tags: ansible

I am running an `ansible-playbook` which have many tasks listed. All of them use to get run one by one, but I want to `pause` the playbook after a particular tasks to asks the user if he wants to continue running the rest of the tasks or exit. I have seen the `pause module` of ansible but couldn't see any example which asks users for yes or no which in turn continue or exit the ansible-playbook accordingly.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The [`pause`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pause_module.html) module actually does exactly that. But it does not give you an option to answer `yes` or `no`. Instead it expects the user to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and then <kbd>a</kbd> for abort. To continue the user simply needs to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Since this is not perfectly obvious to the user you can describe it in the `prompt` parameter.

```
- name: Exterminate mankind
  pause:
    prompt: Please confirm you want to exterminate mankind! Press return to continue. Press Ctrl+c and then "a" to abort
```

Comment: You can extend this to also register a variable and then subsequent tasks can execute based on the value of the "user_input" key. More info. can be found here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/modules/pause_module.html

Comment: Do you know of a way to do this for each host instead of just the whole group?

Comment: It's complicated :) You can just add a `with_items: "{{ ansible_play_batch }}"` and it will prompt for every host separately. So you could prompt the user to confirm every host. But hitting `Ctrl+C` will kill the whole play, not take a single host out of the play. You could instruct the user to instead press `C`, register the task output and then in a separate task check if the user entered `C` and use the `fail` module to take the host out of the play.

Comment: But it is even little more tricky, since the pause module is ran in context of the _first_ host. So the registered var will not be available on all hosts and you'll need to access it via the global `hostvars` array.

Comment: Maybe it's helpful to use the `free` strategy. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html Haven't tested this but it should make the `pause` run in context of every host separately and no loop is required. `Ctrl+C` though would probably still kill the whole play, but it then is easy to access the registered var.

Answer (score 22):

I need to reboot all hosts but I can't risk letting a user to do so by just pressing 'Enter'.

For a true yes/no confirmation in the middle of a playbook, I searched quite a while before finding [this post](https://scriptingis.life/cool-ansible-2/).  How to do this is not so well described in Ansible documentation, but here is the code:

```
- name: Confirm important file deletion
  pause:
    prompt: "Are you sure you want to delete backup.db? (yes/no)"
  register: confirm_delete

- name: Delete backup file
  file:
    path: /home/admin/backup.db
    state: absent
  when: confirm_delete.user_input | bool
```

Comment: I think this is a better solution

Comment: The only issue I found with this solution is that it interprets anything other than "yes" (including any garbage input such as "jaksfd") as "false".  For my use case, I would rather that garbage input raise an exception/error, since the user's intentions are unclear.  Maybe it is possible to adjust the filter in the when clause to incorporate this behavior?  I will experiment.

Comment: I ended up using an "assert" task to validate that user input is exactly one of "yes" or "no".

Comment: I think this only works if you're defining a single host. Otherwise it will register the variable to the hostvars of the first host that runs the command and then the when condition will only skip tasks that run against that host. Tasks for remaining hosts will just outright fail due to not finding the `confirm_delete`  var. You can get around this by using `delegate_to: localhost` and lookup localhost's hostvars but meh.

Answer (score 9):

A good way to achieve prompt for each task without modifying the playbook itself is to use the `--step` option of `ansible-playbook` command.
This will allow you to confirm each step before it is run. You have options here to select `(N)o/(y)es/(c)ontinue`. `N` skips this step, `y` runs the step and `c` continues the rest of the playbook without further prompting *(useful when you're debugging and are past the troublesome place.)* 
Note that also works fine with the `--check` option.

Official Ansible documentation is here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_startnstep.html#step

Answer (score 2):

The other answers (1) require re-checking the input in each subsequent task, (2) require input at each subsequent task, or (3) interpret no input as "yes" (fine for tests, but dangerous if the task is destructive).

---

You can use the following to stop the playbook immediately if the user enters a non-truthy value:

```yaml
---
- name: Task
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Confirm
      ansible.builtin.pause:
        prompt: "Do you really want to continue? (yes/no)"
      register: confirm_continue
      failed_when: not (confirm_continue.user_input | bool)
    - name: Continued
      debug:
        msg: This message is only shown if you wrote '1', 'yes', or 'true'.
    - name: Continued further
      debug:
        msg: The same goes for this message.
```

In the first task, the [pause module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pause_module.html) reads the user's input, [filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html) the user input using `| bool`, and fails the task if the input is not truthy. (Truthy values are `1`, `yes`, and `true.`) The `debug:` can be replaced with any other task.

Therefore, the second task (and all subsequent tasks) do not run if the user entered a non-truthy value in the first task.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work like this, working on a server failover playbook, it takes in couple of responses from the user who runs the playbook, then proceeds with last step "echo results" only if the user types in the correct prompts

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  vars_files:
    - vars/ch.yaml

  tasks:
    - name: Enter server Role
      pause:
        prompt: "\nEnter new role for this server: primary or standby\n\n[primary|standby]"
      register: role

    - name: Enter server Mode
      pause:
        prompt: "\nEnter the Mode of server: fullstack, trading, data\n\n[full|trading|data]"
      register: mode

    - name: confirm proceed
      pause:
        prompt: "\nProceed with failover of {{ansible_hostname|upper}} to become {{ role.user_input|upper }} with {{ mode.user_input|upper }} mode?\n\n[y/n]"
      register: proceed


    - name: echo results
      shell: echo "role {{ role.user_input }}, mode {{ mode.user_input}}" > file
      when: (proceed.user_input == "y" or proceed.user_input == "yes") and
        (role.user_input in ["primary", "standby"]) and
        (mode.user_input in ["full", "data", "trading"])
```