# Ansible prompt with jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, ansible, prompt

I'm running an Ansible playbook where I've added a "prompt" command to install one or other software depending on the user input.

At the playbook execution under Jenkins, there is :
"WARNING : Not waiting for response to prompt as stdin is not interactive".

I've been inspired by several topics as

[pause ansible playbook for user confirmation, whether to run rest tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34290525/pause-ansible-playbook-for-user-confirmation-whether-to-run-rest-tasks)

or

[Ansible - Using user input to chose a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369834/ansible-using-user-input-to-chose-a-variable)

or

[Ansible vars_prompt for roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504663/ansible-vars-prompt-for-roles)

to make some tries, but the same WARNING appears each time.

I've wondered if there was a parameter to add in the ansible.cfg file to force the interactive mode, or something "mandatory" to write in the playbook (I've searched on https://docs.ansible.com/), but found nothing on GooXX either.

Comment: Please make this an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show/describe in detail how you are launching your playbook.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a Jenkins feature. Jenkins launches job as non-interactive mode so you wouldn’t be able to take parameter *from ansible playbook* while the job is executing.

You can however move the required parameter to Jenkins job for user input and then pass to ansible. For example, in case of jenkins pipeline [parameters](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters) block can be used. These parameters then can be passed to ansible via `--extra-vars` and/or `extras` option of [ansible](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ansible/) plugin.